# How to specify a search query as a whole word, not as a part of a word

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to search, amongst others, for the word 'EAN' in Google Search. However the results I'm getting treat my query as a part of a word, e.g. results with the word 'mean'.

My question is: how can I search specifically for a whole word? I tried searching " ean ", but the result was the same as without the spaces and quotation marks.

Comment: Hmm. Searching for EAN (without quotes) and "EAN" both produce aroind 125,000,000 results. I don't see mean (on the first couple of pages of results) except as part of "Ean - meaning of Ean name" which is a valid match.

Comment: @DavidPostill I wrote "amongst other" - I'm searching for a product's ean code, like 'ibuprophen ean' (this returns correct results). However the product I'm searching for does not give me any EAN results, just results like articles about my product containing the word "mean". That's the reason for my question.

Comment: Can you give me an example search which doesn't work how you would like?

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm searching for 'colobreathe ean'. Trying to exclude results like "mean", I search for ' colobreathe " ean " ', which gave me the exact same results. Is there a pattern to exclude unwanted results like the "mean" ones?

Comment: VTC - migrate to web apps

Answer (score 4):

#### how can I search specifically for a whole word?

You can achieve what you want using the `Verbatim` link on the returned results (the default is `All Results`).

Note:

- If you are using the newer search interface, open "Search Tools" and change "All results" to "Verbatim".

---

#### Results before selecting `Verbatim`

[image]

---

#### Results after selecting `Verbatim`

[image]